# Java fastest way to change chars

Tags: java, android

```
      sLine = sLine.replaceAll("&&", "&"); 
      sLine = sLine.replaceAll(((char)245)+"", "ő");
      sLine = sLine.replaceAll(((char)213)+"", "Ő");
      sLine = sLine.replaceAll(((char)361)+"", "ű");
      sLine = sLine.replaceAll(((char)251)+"", "ű");
```

Is there a way to to this only one line? This is very slow on big strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve performance by using precompiled regular expressions. Under the hood `String.replaceAll` is going to compile and apply a regular expression for you anyway. As compilation of the regexp is *relatively* computationally intensive, this should improve performance when executing this code frequently.

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN_1 = Pattern.compile("\u00f5");
private static final Pattern PATTERN_2 = Pattern.compile(Character.toString((char) 241));

String original = new String("A" + (char) 245 + "\u00f1" + "D");
String replaced2 = PATTERN_1.matcher(original).replaceAll("B");
replaced2 = PATTERN_2.matcher(replaced2).replaceAll("C");
System.out.println(original + " -> " + replaced2);
```

Will print out:

> A??D -> ABCD

When working with a very very long `String` this probably won't offer much performance over what you proposed.

**As an aside:**
Using non UTF-8 characters in code will cause you (and your colleagues) pain down the road. You should use [Unicode characters](http://oreilly.com/actionscript/excerpts/as3-cookbook/appendix.html) or, as you were, character decimal representations at all times.

Comment: For replacing a *single* character pattern, I doubt that regular expressions are faster than `replaceAll`. It's not the pattern that is expensive, it's the number of string operations.

Comment: True. Would be nice if we could put them all into a single regex but I can't figure out a way to do a 'pairwise' replace like s/[abc]/ABC/.. don't think it's possible?

Comment: Perl etc. have a `tr///` command for that. `tr/A-Z/B-ZA/` for example is ROT-1. But here, IMHO, he should really be using a proper charset decoder instead of trying to do this for the few characters he knows himself.

Comment: I didn't know about `tr`, cheers! Agreed, if it's charset decoding he's after, but if not I think a transliteration regex is the ticket.

Answer (score 5):

Consider converting the string to a `char[]` and then iterating over the array manually.

Avoid string concatenation such as `((char)245)+""`. Use a character constant.

But it looks like you are trying to *fix the encoding of strings* manually? That is a *really bad idea*. Because next week, you will have a user with the `ü` character. And then, someone will use a `€` currency value. And then a spanish user will want to use the `¿` character. How many `replaceAll` are you willing to add?!?

Look at how to **encode/decode/recode strings**.

Maybe use the following constructor instead:

```
String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
```

and look at the Java Charset classes:

- [java.nio.charset.Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)
- [java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html)
- [java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html)

Comment: yeah I am using the charset, and it is UTF8 now, the only probleme is that the RIGHT char is "ő", but from the server what I gave is ((char)245), so I can't figure it how to replace those chars.

Comment: Find out what charset your server sends, and *decode* it correctly! Don't try to reinvent charset decoding via `replaceAll`, it does not scale. Are you sure that A) your server sends UTF-8, and B) your application also uses UTF-8 everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String char1       = Character.toString((char) 245);
private static final String char2       = Character.toString((char) 213);
private static final String char3       = Character.toString((char) 361);
private static final String char4       = Character.toString((char) 251);

private static final Pattern PATTERN_1  = Pattern.compile(char1);
private static final Pattern PATTERN_2  = Pattern.compile(char2);
private static final Pattern PATTERN_3  = Pattern.compile(char3);
private static final Pattern PATTERN_4  = Pattern.compile(char4);

public static String replaceAccents(String sLine) {

    String replaced=sLine;

    if (replaced.contains(char1)) replaced  = PATTERN_1.matcher(replaced).replaceAll("ő");
    if (replaced.contains(char2)) replaced  = PATTERN_2.matcher(replaced).replaceAll("Ő");      
    if (replaced.contains(char3)) replaced  = PATTERN_3.matcher(replaced).replaceAll("Ű");
    if (replaced.contains(char4)) replaced  = PATTERN_4.matcher(replaced).replaceAll("ű");      

    return replaced;
}
```

Here is the final and fast code for that, thanks to Sean.